# Как работает Devtools Chrome с android?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

Мне нужно получить сетевые события из Chrome. Я нашел вот это 
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/
Кажется, что Chrome использует порт для получения сообщений, ответов и отправки событий для удаленной отладки. В нем говорится, что он использует JSON. То есть можно отправить http Запрос на localhost: ? который вернет список открытых вкладок . И уже к ним подключиться и редактировать Html код

Comment: Нет никакого выхода, зачем вам менять что-то на вкладках?

Comment: как тогда работает Devtools ? Выход есть )